# Slow query on (un-indexed) big table

Tags: mysql, performance

I have this table plc_data:

```
MariaDB []> select * from plc_data order by data_ora desc limit 50;
+----------------------------------+---------+---------------------+
| nome                             | valore  | data_ora            |
+----------------------------------+---------+---------------------+
| AN_SILOS1.PESO-PRODOTTO-CARICATO | 127.771 | 2016-11-07 09:35:06 |
| AN_SILOS2.PESO-PRODOTTO-CARICATO | 383.813 | 2016-11-07 09:35:06 |
| AN_SILOS3.PESO-PRODOTTO-CARICATO | 224.913 | 2016-11-07 09:35:06 |
| AN_SILOS4.PESO-PRODOTTO-CARICATO | 331.064 | 2016-11-07 09:35:06 |
| AN_SILOS5.PESO-PRODOTTO-CARICATO | 276.469 | 2016-11-07 09:35:06 |
| AN_SILOS6.PESO-PRODOTTO-CARICATO | 303.538 | 2016-11-07 09:35:06 |
| AN_SILOS7.PESO-PRODOTTO-CARICATO | 54.7685 | 2016-11-07 09:35:06 |
| AN_SILOS8.PESO-PRODOTTO-CARICATO | 31.8234 | 2016-11-07 09:35:06 |
| ON-EV.QEV1                       |       0 | 2016-11-07 09:35:06 |
| ON-EV.QEV2                       |       0 | 2016-11-07 09:35:06 |
| ON-EV.QEV3                       |       0 | 2016-11-07 09:35:06 |
| ON-EV.QEV4                       |       0 | 2016-11-07 09:35:06 |
| ON-EV.QEV5                       |       0 | 2016-11-07 09:35:06 |
| ON-EV.QEV6                       |       0 | 2016-11-07 09:35:06 |
| ON-EV.QEV7                       |       0 | 2016-11-07 09:35:06 |
| ON-EV.QEV8                       |       0 | 2016-11-07 09:35:06 |
| MARCIA_9                         |       0 | 2016-11-07 09:35:06 |
| MARCIA_10                        |       0 | 2016-11-07 09:35:06 |
| AN_SILOS1.PESO-PRODOTTO-CARICATO |  127.88 | 2016-11-07 09:30:07 |
| AN_SILOS2.PESO-PRODOTTO-CARICATO | 383.813 | 2016-11-07 09:30:07 |
| AN_SILOS3.PESO-PRODOTTO-CARICATO | 224.935 | 2016-11-07 09:30:07 |
| AN_SILOS4.PESO-PRODOTTO-CARICATO | 331.064 | 2016-11-07 09:30:07 |
| AN_SILOS5.PESO-PRODOTTO-CARICATO |  253.48 | 2016-11-07 09:30:07 |
| AN_SILOS6.PESO-PRODOTTO-CARICATO | 303.517 | 2016-11-07 09:30:07 |
| AN_SILOS7.PESO-PRODOTTO-CARICATO | 54.7685 | 2016-11-07 09:30:07 |
| AN_SILOS8.PESO-PRODOTTO-CARICATO | 31.8256 | 2016-11-07 09:30:07 |
| ON-EV.QEV1                       |       0 | 2016-11-07 09:30:07 |
| ON-EV.QEV2                       |       0 | 2016-11-07 09:30:07 |
| ON-EV.QEV3                       |       0 | 2016-11-07 09:30:07 |
| ON-EV.QEV4                       |       0 | 2016-11-07 09:30:07 |
| ON-EV.QEV5                       |       0 | 2016-11-07 09:30:07 |
| ON-EV.QEV6                       |       0 | 2016-11-07 09:30:07 |
| ON-EV.QEV7                       |       0 | 2016-11-07 09:30:07 |
| ON-EV.QEV8                       |       0 | 2016-11-07 09:30:07 |
| MARCIA_9                         |       0 | 2016-11-07 09:30:07 |
| MARCIA_10                        |       0 | 2016-11-07 09:30:07 |
| AN_SILOS1.PESO-PRODOTTO-CARICATO | 127.815 | 2016-11-07 09:25:06 |
| AN_SILOS2.PESO-PRODOTTO-CARICATO | 383.748 | 2016-11-07 09:25:06 |
| AN_SILOS3.PESO-PRODOTTO-CARICATO | 225.391 | 2016-11-07 09:25:06 |
| AN_SILOS4.PESO-PRODOTTO-CARICATO | 331.172 | 2016-11-07 09:25:06 |
| AN_SILOS5.PESO-PRODOTTO-CARICATO | 257.388 | 2016-11-07 09:25:06 |
| AN_SILOS6.PESO-PRODOTTO-CARICATO | 303.538 | 2016-11-07 09:25:06 |
| AN_SILOS7.PESO-PRODOTTO-CARICATO |  54.204 | 2016-11-07 09:25:06 |
| AN_SILOS8.PESO-PRODOTTO-CARICATO | 31.8278 | 2016-11-07 09:25:06 |
| ON-EV.QEV1                       |       0 | 2016-11-07 09:25:06 |
| ON-EV.QEV2                       |       0 | 2016-11-07 09:25:06 |
| ON-EV.QEV3                       |       0 | 2016-11-07 09:25:06 |
| ON-EV.QEV4                       |       0 | 2016-11-07 09:25:06 |
| ON-EV.QEV5                       |       1 | 2016-11-07 09:25:06 |
| ON-EV.QEV6                       |       0 | 2016-11-07 09:25:06 |
+----------------------------------+---------+---------------------+
50 rows in set (1.96 sec)
```

As you can see the query get about 2 seconds to execute!

While the next query selecting only last saved values is incredibly slow (about 34sec):

```
SELECT `T1`.`nome`, `T1`.`valore`, `T1`.`data_ora` 
  FROM `plc_data` `T1` 
  WHERE data_ora = (select max(T2.data_ora) 
                      from plc_data T2 
                      where T1.nome = `T2`.`nome`)
```

Actually the table has 311,814 rows and grows about  4,600 rows a day.

How can I speed up the table selecting?

Comment: Um... add indexes then?

Comment: This looks like an update log for a key->value association where you want the latest version of each key. It would help to denormalize this a bit and keep a copy of the latest value in its own table (i.e. a "materialized view").

Answer (score 1):

You should create proper index on column nome and data_ora
but you can also try  (with or without index) to use this query

```
SELECT `T1`.`nome`, `T1`.`valore`, `T2`.`data_ora` 
FROM `plc_data` `T1`
INNER JOIN (
      SELECT nome,  max(data_ora)  data_ora
      FROM plc_data 
      GROUP BY nome
 )  T2 on T1.name = t2.name 
      AND t1.data_ora = t2.data_ora
```

Comment: I don't think that there will be a speed-improvement unless you add an index.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar  I have experinced that   in some case mysql sql create dinamically a table for this kind of  join based  on subquery and this can improve the  significatively the performance

Comment: Hmmm - and how would MySQL quickly determine the rows that should go into that dynamic table? It would still have to filter on one or more columns (the ones in the `on` clause). That's why I doubt it will be quicker.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar   . this could be useful  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/subquery-optimization.html

Comment: You query is faster and seems more efficient: 
`312066 rows in set (9.89 sec)` (with added indexes).

But consider that i don't need all this rows! My query search only for last values. 
If I add "LIMIT 18" the executing time is only 4sec. But i want all distinct LAST values available.

Comment: I struggle to understand .. what do you mean with "But consider that i do not need all this rows". You want to use a filter (where)? to find the last value, mysql should still scan the tables (in which you can go back useful to an index), or you need only 18 lines. (Random) .. in respect of all the distinct values utime this should already be calculated by the group by

Comment: I mean that your query does not give the same results as the original. And if i add a "GROUP BY" the performance of your query is the same as my quaery. "18"  are the distinct rows ( "nome") i need (not random).

Comment: I have update  the answer (you need  t2.data_ora)   .. hope is useful

Comment: I did not see the data_ora, so added it.

Comment: It really needs `INDEX(nome, data_ora)`.  With that, it is a good example of [_Groupwise max_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/groupwise_max#using_an_uncorrelated_subquery)

Answer (score 0):

Add an index on the `data_ora` table. That's the minimum.

A general rule of thumb is: For every combination of fields in a `where` clause you use there should be an index, except if there's an index that starts with the fields in your clause in the correct order.

Examples:

```
WHERE field1 = x AND field2 = y AND field3 = z
```

=> You should have an index for `field1, field2, field3`.

```
WHERE field1 = x and field2 = y
```

=> You don't need a new index. This is covered by above index.

```
WHERE field3 = x AND field2 = y AND field1 = z
```

=> You should have an index for `field3, field2, field1` unless you detect that the query optimizer is smart enough to re-order the fields in the `where` clause to use your first index, which is not always possible.

But the most important thing to remember is: **If you have a `where` clause, there must be an index.**

Comment: (@mendosi @Jon-Stirling too)
The index on "data_ora" incredibly speed-up the first query:
    `50 rows in set (0.01 sec)`

An index on "nome" speed-up the second query:
    `18 rows in set (8.92 sec)`

But in a month the rows will be doubled.  Is this the max performance can i obtain ?

Comment: Having a closer look, a single index on both `nom` and `data_ora` should serve the second query better than one only on `nom`.